# paypal doExpressCheckoutPayment invalid PayerID every single time

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Why is everything PayPal so crazy hard?

### This is what I'm sending to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp :

METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment&
VERSION=108.0&
USER=my-sandbox-facilitator_api1.domain.com&
PWD=&
SIGNATURE=&
SUBJECT=&
TOKEN=EC-1GE68226PG526154U&
PAYERID=my-sandbox-buyer%40domain.com
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19.95&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL=

### This is what I'm getting back:

TIMESTAMP=2015-12-12T21%3a35%3a34Z&
CORRELATIONID=d9a463bfa6bb4&
ACK=Failure&
VERSION=108.0&
BUILD=18308778&
L_ERRORCODE0=10406&
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Transaction+refused+because+of+an+invalid+argument.+See+additional+error+messages+for+details.&
L_LONGMESSAGE0=The+PayerID+value+is+invalid.&
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

Just before this I did a METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails without any problems.
    PayerID wasn't invalid for that?!?!!
I have a token so I did a METHOD=SetExpressCheckout without any problems.

Ideas?
No amount of Google had a working answer for me.
Either did PP's 5(!) tech support sites.

It is the same issue even if I reconfigure and and shoot a similar transaction at my live PP.

Answer (score 0):

`PAYERID` is a unique PayPal buyer account identification number as returned after SetExpressCheckout API call(after buyer login to paypal and gets redirected to your RETURN URL , you will need to copy that PAyer Id and use in Doexpresscheckout request. Payer is a  13 single-byte alphanumeric character and not an email address.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Vimalnith.  This is from the page you sent:
(Required) Unique PayPal buyer account identification number **as returned in the GetExpressCheckoutDetails response**. PayPal also appends the payer ID as a GET parameter named PayerID to your RETURN URL when redirecting the buyer back to your website from paypal.com. Character length and limitations: 13 single-byte alphanumeric characters.
Why would the response to my GetExpressCheckoutDetail contain PayerID = null if there wasn't an error and my sandbox test email buyer is what I pass to the GetExpressCheckoutDetail?

Comment: GetExpressCheckoutDetail is optional.  You don't have to use it.  So I believe this means if you do not use it them you have to send the buyer's email address.

Comment: You should get the ec token and payer id in the return URL, what's the return URL you get back after you login to PayPal

Comment: _Maybe this is where I'm wrong?_  **1)** If I send the email address to GetExpressCheckoutDetail why do I not get the PayerID back? & **2)**  If I don't first call GetExpressCheckoutDetail to first retrieve that PayerID then how do I retrieve the PayerID before calling DoExpressCheckoutPayment?

Comment: Ignore getexprescheckout,  you just make the setexpress api call,  PayPal will give you back the token and payer id (after you redirect,login) in the return URL

Comment: Are you saying the user in their browser commits some action that causes me to send a SetCheckoutExpress. What I send includes the ReturnURL.  When I do this I get a response.  In the response is the ec Token.  But in the response a modified version the ReturnURL is not included.  At this point of the transaction the user's browser does know or do anything does it?

Comment: The Setexpresscheckout API response will not include Payer id, it returns only Token. Did you redirect the user to this endpoint "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=tokenValue" and made the user login to paypal in the paypal checkout page?

Comment: I just messaged you on techycommerce.  I think you are really close to something but it just isn't quite there yet.  Where does sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin come in at all.  Dozens of examples & reams of documents I've read and I've NEVER seen that URL

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/

Comment: I really appreciate the references.  But PP documentation was not written for people to read.  I've even downloaded and stood up PP's own example wed site/solution/app - and that doesn't even work.